# Mysql - Load data infile - skip column in Mysql version 4

Tags: mysql, file, import, load-data-infile

I'm trying to import some data to database using: load data infile.

For example:

I have table (name: **tab**) with two columns: `colA`, `colB`.

In file there are three columns, example file content: `value1|value2|value3`

I want that value2 goes to colA and value3 goes to colB. I don't need value1.

In Mysql 5 I did it like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE <filename>
REPLACE
INTO TABLE tab
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'
(@dummy, colA, colB);
```

It works great but the problem is when I try do it in **Mysql 4**. There is an error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@dummy, colA, colB)' at line 6
```

I checked in mysql documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/load-data.html and in mysql 4 values from file can't be save to user variable (in my example to @dummy).

Do you have any ideas how to import (using load data infile) only some columns from file in Mysql 4?

Thanks

Comment: Why on EARTH are you using MySQL 4?  It's not 1990 anymore...

Comment: I'm not using. There is a very old application using it and i had to work with it. This is also very big application which is using by many customers and upgrade to mysql 5 is not so easy. :P

Answer (score 1):

You could load the data into a temporary table and then use [`REPLACE ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/replace.html):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptab LIKE tab;
ALTER TABLE tmptab ADD COLUMN dummy TEXT;

LOAD DATA INFILE <filename>
  INTO TABLE tmptab
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'
  (dummy, colA, colB);

REPLACE INTO tmp (colA, colB) SELECT (colA, colB) FROM tmptab;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmptab;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer. It is a good idea but this solve require to create another table, and i afroid that can be slow. Maybe there is a solution without creating temporary table ?

Comment: Finally i done it this way. It worked not so bad (although i had many files with many rekords). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A comment to the last answer(Since I am unable to comment):

If the code:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE <filename>
  INTO TABLE tmptab
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'
  (dummy, colA, colB);
```

-leads to some warning, then use:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE <filename>
  INTO TABLE tmptab
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  (@dummy, colA, colB);
```

Thank You.